# Only Youtube audio Playing but not Video in Iphone WebView

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, video, uiwebview, youtube

I am trying to play youtube videos after loading the webview. But Only Audio is being played, not video. Although I get play button in status bar, the Media Player does not become active. The Same piece of code works in iTouch 4.1 and simulator but not on iPhone 4.1/4.0. What am I missing here???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the default youtube application playing video? If yes, You might want to try removing the frameworks, add them again and clean build your project.